# setState containing object=>array=> objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

What i have is

```
const [productData, setproductData] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    price: "",
    selectedFile: "",
    images: [{ _id: "", urls: "" }],
  });
```

How i will change the values inside  **IMAGES** object. I want to change id and Urls.

I have tried the following methods but unsuccessful.

```
  setproductData({
    ...productData,
    images: [...productData.images._id, i],  //where i is any id or number
  });
```

but when i try to execute it it says **productData.images.id** is not iterable. Can any help plz...

Comment: Do you want `images` to contain exactly one element after you set the new value, or do you want to add a new object to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `newId` is your new _id, and `newUrls` is your new urls

```
setProductData(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  images: [...prev.images, {_id: newId, urls: newUrls}]
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well, But when i add another ID or URLs it overwrites the last known values. Any idea why it is happening

Comment: Ok, so your question is: How do you add a new object to the array. I updated the answer

Comment: yes, you can say so that it dont overwrite previous values.

Comment: Thanks for your help @hellogoodnight! Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
 setproductData({
    ...productData,
    images: [{...productData.images[0], _id: i}], 
  });
```

if you want to modify selected id just use

```
    setproductData({
        ...productData,
        images: productData.images.map((image) => {
          if (image._id === i) return {...image} // modify here
          return image
        }), 
    });
```

Comment: Solution worked fine at first attempt, But when i try to add another ID or URLs, it overwrites the last known values. Any idea why its happening

Comment: how about this: images: [...productData.images, yourNewObject]